# ELK Stack - Parse message eset

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash

Получаю syslog  из eset, в поле message вся информация которая нужно парсить и создать отделныйе филды, Написал grok который работает в grokdebuger кибаны: 
подскажыте пожалуйста где я ошыбся.

Пример информации в поле message

```
<13>1 2019-11-22T10:20:31.316Z Server-ESET ERAServer 10160 - - Threat type: trojan Threat name: HTML/ScrInject.B Computer name: XX.YY.ZZ Logged user: ZZ\aa.bb Time of occurrence: 11/22/19, 1:18:56 PM UTC+4 Scanner: HTTP filter Action performed: connection terminated
```

Вот грок каторый я написал:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:RequestedHost} %{WORD:environment} %{NOTSPACE:ID:string}\s*-\s*-\s*%{WORD} %{WORD}:\s*%{WORD:Tread_Type}\s*%{WORD}\s*%{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA:Thread_name}Computer%{SPACE}name: %{HOSTNAME:Host} %{WORD} %{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA:USER}Time%{SPACE}of%{SPACE}occurrence:%{SPACE}%{MONTHNUM}[//]%{MONTHDAY}[//]%{YEAR},%{GREEDYDATA:Time}
```

Конфиг:

```
filter
{
    if[type] == "syslog" {
        if[host] == "xxx.yyy.zzz.ccc" {
            grok {
                    match => {"message" => ["%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:RequestedHost} %{WORD:environment} %{NOTSPACE:ID:string}\s*-\s*-\s*%{WORD} %{WORD}:\s*%{WORD:Tread_Type}\s*%{WORD}\s*%{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA:Thread_name}Computer%{SPACE}name: %{HOSTNAME:Host} %{WORD} %{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA:USER}Time%{SPACE}of%{SPACE}occurrence:%{SPACE}%{MONTHNUM}[//]%{MONTHDAY}[//]%{YEAR},%{GREEDYDATA:Time}"]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в логах Eset, там была оин символ который должен был скипнуть 
рабочий грок

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:RequestedHost} %{WORD:environment} %{NOTSPACE:ID:string}\s*-\s*-\s*\S+ Threat\s*type:\s*%{WORD:Tread_Type}\s*Threat\s*name: %{GREEDYDATA:Thread_name}Computer%{SPACE}name: %{HOSTNAME:Host} %{WORD} %{WORD}:%{GREEDYDATA:USER}Time%{SPACE}of%{SPACE}occurrence:%{SPACE}%{MONTHNUM}[//]%{MONTHDAY}[//]%{YEAR},%{GREEDYDATA:Time}